# Reading RSS feed

Tags: php, xml, rss

I need to read an XML file, i watched some tutorials and tried different sollutions, but for some reason I can't figure out why it doenst work.

The XML file that I want to read: http://www.voetbalzone.nl/rss/rss.xml

This is the code that im using:

```
$xml= "http://www.voetbalzone.nl/rss/rss.xml"

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    $title = $xml->rss->channel->item[$i]->title;
}
```

The error I get: Premature end of data in tag

Comment: post whole php code you are trying to work with , this is not a complete code !. nobody will get the error if you will not show the code of how you fetching the xml, and if this is your whole code then , i have to say , it's totally incomplete and wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me like this:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.voetbalzone.nl/rss/rss.xml");

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    $title = $xml->channel->item[$i]->title;
}

?>
```

Note that you are overwriting the variable `$title` each time, so that you will have the title of the 10. element in it after the loop finished [I assume that is not what you want?]

To get all 'item'-Elements inside 'channel' as an Array to iterate through you can use xpath like this:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.voetbalzone.nl/rss/rss.xml");

$item_array = $xml->xpath("//rss/channel/item");

foreach($item_array as $item) {
    echo $item->title . "\n";
}
?>
```

I would suggest to read about php's SimpleXML here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: Thanks WireMonkey, I edited the code like this: http://pastebin.com/LFLZLkFq

I saved the whole XML file from the link http://www.voetbalzone.nl/rss/rss.xml as "vz.xml", only than all the content from the file will load without errors.

If I use the link, http://www.voetbalzone.nl/rss/rss.xml to get the information from the RSS feed than the page will take like a minute to load and after that ill get a lot of error messages while loading the XML file. Image: http://s1.postimg.org/fswdjt23h/Naamloos.png

Comment: Hello @Nibboro, I tested your latest code on an apache2 webserver and on [phpfiddle.com](http://phpfiddle.com) and it seems working for me (and without noteworthy latency). I guess there must be something wrong with your setup that leads to these errors.